# Degraded multi-touch touchscreen capabilities from 18.04 to 19.10

Tags: touchscreen, multi-touch, wayland, onscreen-keyboard

I just got my new Lenovo L13 Yoga, and briefly tested several Live-Versions in order to get the best solution out of the box. My experience (tested w/ Firefox and LibreOffice Draw):

**Ubuntu 19.10 (Gnome)**:

- no multi-touch (two finger moves simply mark, no pinch & zoom etc)
- on-screen keyboard comes up in tablet mode, but in, e.g. Firefox address line, it takes two touch-inputs to type one letter (there's apparently an interference with the auto-completion).

**Xubuntu 19.10 (Xfce)**:

- no multi-touch (as above)
- no on-screen keyboard

**Ubuntu 18.04**:

- multi-touch does work
- on-screen keyboard comes up in tablet mode, works good (no navigation keys though)

**Mint 19.3**

- multi-touch works (subjectively better than in Gnome)
- on-screen keyboard comes up in tablet mode
- WiFi isn't recognized

Does anyone have a suggestion for an easy work-around or a distro which may work better? I just intent to bridge the time until Ubuntu 20.04 LTS comes out (April), and would like to spent as little effort as possible for moving from my current system (Xubuntu 19.10) to the temporary solution now.
I didn't see a way to test wayland on live Ubuntu, which may solve the touch issues. I'd appreciate suggestions on that as well.

Thanks in advance! B.

Comment: Mint is off-topic as it's not Ubuntu nor official flavor of Ubuntu (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).  You didn't mention which kernel you tried in 18.04 (ie. GA 4.15 or HWE 5.3),   I would download & boot 20.04 in 'live' mode to see how it'll perform now...

Comment: You can test wayland with live (using persistence), and on-screen keyboard can be made to show for Xubuntu 19.10

Comment: I'd give a try with 20.04 (you can get the beta version ISO's somewhere), just to see how well it'll work (if it works great, you can even install it, and then when it comes out, you'll be offered to upgrade to the final release version - just beware that it's not supported here, so folks here won't answer questions about it. With Mint, IIRC you somehow have to specifically choose to use the newer kernel, which would probably make the WiFi work.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I wasn't aware that 20.04 beta is already available. 

Also, I didn't check which kernel version was loaded. I wasn't even aware that the live-version comes with different kernel generations. Will check later today.

Now, "persistance" - is that some software I've never heard of, or would I need to be persistent in order to make wayland work?

Comment: v20.04 from yesterday isn't stable enough for the live version to boot up completely on my system (restarts automatically during the process).I did install Xubuntu 19.10 now, and multi-touch doesn't work (as expected), and neither does wifi (unexpected, and a different topic, but unfortunately the more pressing issue than getting wayland to work or figuring out what guiverc meant with "persistence").